# How to remap control key in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to keep control key for `term` under `emacs`. How can I rebind existing mappings to some other key (e.g. Right-<kbd>CNTL</kbd>)?

Comment: X11-only solution is also acceptable.

Comment: Have you tried reading this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html)